# When does compression increase file size?

Tags: python-2.7, file-io, compression, lzw

I have a large text file which mainly consists of numbers and some delimiters like `,|{}[]:` etc. I used Lempel-Ziv encoding for compression. The code I used is not mine and is the one from [Rosetta](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#Python) code. I ran the code for line by line compression as well as once for chunk by chunk compression:

```
def readChunk(file_object, size = 1024):
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data

def readByChunk():
    with open(LARGE_FILE, 'r') as f:
        for data in readChunk(f, 2048):
            compressed_chunk = compress(data)
            compressed_chunk = map(lambda a : str(a), compressed_chunk)
            comp_file.write(" ".join(compressed_chunk))

def readLineByLine():
    with open(LARGE_FILE, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for data in lines:
            compressed_line = compress(data)
            compressed_line = map(lambda a : str(a), compressed_line)
            comp_file.write(" ".join(compressed_line))
```

Both function output a file that is much bigger than the original file!! Decompression works fine i.e. I am able to get the original text back so I think the code is correct.

Am I doing something wrong in saving the file?

Comment: is the content pretty random or does it contain obvious patterns?

Comment: There are no obvious patterns there! Just a lot of numbers separated by `,`s and `|`s.

Answer (score 2):

The compressor you are using is terrible.  Try `zlib.compress` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is "when the data is random bits", or already compressed. 99% of other normal things will compress just fine. For ascii data (like the data you say you are using) really trivial compressors suffice, just Huffman encoding it gets you a decent boost and you're saying you only use like a dozen unique characters.

Which means that either you have a bunch of random data that you're not telling us about or there's a bug in the compressor.

Comment: The data in the original file looks like this `3549=63;7792=413;10695=90;10701=220;11900=81;11903=175;14417=101;14738=9....` every line in the file ends with a `\n`.

Comment: Well something funky's going on, try debugging into it. It may be that e.g. `str(a)` is reencoding or you're accidentally putting `" "` between every byte or something just silly. It does look like it should be fine, though.

Comment: Any normal compressor (zlib, gzip, bz2, lzma, &c) is already going to be doing huffman (and run-length) encoding as a first round anyway.